# React controlled checkbox (toggle) on props.

Tags: reactjs

I need to make a checkbox (toggle, like IOS) component, that doesn't use state and controls only by props. The current code looks like this:

```
export class Checkbox extends React.Component {

handleChange(event) {
   this.props.onChange({value: event.target.value});
}

render() {
    return (
        <span>
             <input class="ios_toggle" type="checkbox"
                 value={this.props.value}
                 disabled={this.props.disabled}
                 onChange={this.handleChange}
             />
        </span>
     );
 }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
<Checkbox value={true} disabled={false} />
```

And it almost works, but:

1. It looks unchecked, even if props equal to `value={true}`
2. By clicking on this toggle it changes, but it shouldn't. I mean, if I put the prop `value={true}`, in theory it'll be the same, no matter what I do with it in browser?

What did I miss?

Comment: Use e.target.checked, not e.target.value. console.log is a useful function for debugging purposes in order to print out variables that are returning values you don't expect.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to use the `checked` property instead of the `value`. Try something like this instead:

```
export class Checkbox extends React.Component {

  handleChange = () => {
     this.props.onChange({ checked: !this.props.checked });
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <span>
               <input class="ios_toggle" type="checkbox"
                   value={this.props.value}
                   disabled={this.props.disabled}
                   checked={this.props.checked}
                   onChange={this.handleChange}
               />
          </span>
       );
   }
}
```

The value property can be anything, but the property that it's actually driving the toggle is called `checked`

Comment: What is the `this` inside `handleChange`? Is it the `Checkbox` component instance? If so, then shouldn't it "call itself?" -- when I try this, if I call `this.props.onChange`, on an `onChange` event in a checkbox input -- then it triggers the `onChange` function i put in the **parent** component's `onChange` prop -- but... why?

Comment: The `this` refers to the current `Checkbox` instance. You get the parent executed because `this.props` is receiving properties from the parent, one of those is `onChange` defined in the parent. eg: `<Checkbox onChange={() => console.log('this is the parent!') } />`

Comment: 1. Use anonymous function `onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}`, or 2. bind `this`, eg. in constructor `this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);`

Comment: So 'value' prop can be omitted?

Comment: Yes, it can be omitted, you really want to know if the property is on/off, right? The value is most likely true/false.