# How to remove the :checked pseudo-class using a controlled component in React?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a subscription selection component that includes 3 individual "plan" components. Each plan component contains a radio button for selecting that plan. Thus, the radio buttons are not grouped together but are actually separated across the 3 components.

I am currently able to successfully "select" each plan appropriately when I click the radio button. The "selected" prop updates accordingly for each plan component, so this functionality is working as it should. The problem is that each radio button visually remains "selected" because the styling is applied via a :checked pseudo-class which does not appear to get updated when another button is clicked.

So in other words, I click button 1 -> button 1 is selected, plan 1 is selected, and plan 1's border color changes. I click button 2 -> butotn 2 is selected, plan 2 is selected, plan 2's border color changes, plan 1 is no longer selected and plan 1's border color reverts back to normal, BUT plan 1's button is still selected.

SubscriptionsContainer.js

```
const SubscriptionsContainer = (props) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('2');
  const plansList = [ 
    {
      ...plan info
    }
  ]

  const selectPlan = (e) => {
    setSelected(e.target.value);
  }

  const plansComponents = plansList.map(plan => (
    <SubscriptionPlan
      key={plan.id}
      id={plan.id}
      title={plan.title}
      price={plan.price}
      feature1={plan.feature1}
      feature2={plan.feature2}
      feature3={plan.feature3}
      feature4={plan.feature4}
      selected={plan.id === selected}
      selectPlan={selectPlan}
    />
    ));

  return (
    <FlexContainer>
      {plansComponents}
    </FlexContainer>
  )
}
```

SubscriptionPlan.js

```
const SubscriptionPlan = ({
  selected,
  id,
  title,
  price,
  feature1,
  feature2,
  feature3,
  feature4,
  selectPlan,
  ...props
}) => {

  return (
    <PlanContainer selected={selected} flexDirection="column">
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <P>{price}/mo</P>
      <P>{feature1}</P>
      <P>{feature2}</P>
      <P>{feature3}</P>
      <P>{feature4}</P>
      <RadioInput onChange={selectPlan} selected={selected} name={id} value={id} />
    </PlanContainer>
  )
};
```

RadioInput.js

```
const RadioInput = (props) => {
  console.log(props.selected);
  return (
    <Item>
      <RadioButton
        type="radio"
        value={props.value}
        selected={props.selected}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        {...props} />
      <RadioButtonStyle/>
      <RadioButtonLabel>{props.value}</RadioButtonLabel>
    </Item>
  )
}

const Item = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 48px;
  position: relative;
`;

const RadioButtonStyle = styled.label`
  position: absolute;
  top: 33%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid ${colors.primary500};
`;
const RadioButton = styled.input`
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  &:hover ~ ${RadioButtonStyle} {
    background: ${colors.secondary500};
    opacity: 0.5;
    border: 1px solid ${colors.secondary600};

    &::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 8px;
      height: 8px;
      margin: 4px;
      background: white;

    }
  }
  &:focus + ${RadioButtonStyle} {
    border: 1px solid ${colors.secondary600};
  }
  &:checked + ${RadioButtonStyle} {
    background: ${colors.secondary500};
    opacity: 1;
    border: 1px solid ${colors.secondary600};
    &::after {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      border-radius: 50%;
      width: 8px;
      height: 8px;
      margin: 4px;
      box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      background: white;
    }
  }
`;

const RadioButtonLabel = styled.div`
  color: ${colors.primary800};
`
```

Comment: If the button is still selected then all of the radio button's must not have the same "name" attribute. Just add name="something" so that all the button's are tied together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the "value" prop on your checkbox component with "checked".

```js
const RadioInput = (props) => {
  console.log(props.selected);
  return (
    <Item>
      <RadioButton
        type="radio"
        // value={props.value} <-- removed
        checked={props.value} // <-- added
        selected={props.selected}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        {...props} />
      <RadioButtonStyle/>
      <RadioButtonLabel>{props.value}</RadioButtonLabel>
    </Item>
  )
}
```

See possible duplicate question: [React controlled checkbox (toggle) on props.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617722/react-controlled-checkbox-toggle-on-props)

Comment: Thanks! I actually needed to keep value={props.value} since my onChange function used e.target.value to change the state, so I passed down a checked prop to my radio input that was based on the selected state, so "selected={props.selected}". This works now, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can group by giving all the inputs the same name like `name="subscriptionType"` even if they are in separate components.

Hope the helps