# Get the checkbox value in node.js

Tags: html, node.js, checkbox, request

I want to access the checkbox value form request.body in node.js. I tried logging it but the console says 'undefined.'

> HTML

```
 <label>
       <input name='sell' type='checkbox' value='false' />I want to sell this photo.
 </label>
```

> Node.js

```
   const { title, description, category, sell } = req.body;
   console.log(req.body);
   console.log(sell);
```

The other data from the request body is being logged out but the checkbox (sell) is undefined. I cannot figure out what is wrong..

Answer (score 1):

Only successful controls will be submitted to the server.

A checkbox is only successful if:

- It has a `name`
- It is checked

We can see your checkbox has a name, so, since the rest of your data isn't coming through, the problem is that it isn't checked.

Given that you have given it a value of `false` I'd suspect you might be using client side JS to toggle it's value between `true` and `false`. If so, don't do that.

Determine if it is checked or not based on its presence. Force it to a boolean state on the server if you need an explicit boolean.

```
const booleanSell = !!sell;
console.log(booleanSell).
```

Comment: I am storing the checkbox in react states, initially it is set to false and when checkbox is clicked, it is 'true'.
The thing is, how can I set it to true as a property and not as a string 'true' .
And another thing, when toggling the checkbox, the state is not changing to false once it is set to true..

Comment: @Coder111 — That's a completely different problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45617722/react-controlled-checkbox-toggle-on-props/45617879